# Iptables redirect outside requests to 127.0.0.1 (VirtualBox)

Tags: networking, iptables, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-interface

I have a guest virtual machine installed with the output:

`ifconfig`:

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 inet 10.0.2.15 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.2.255 inet6 fe80::e7a2:d6ce:7f7:aff3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20 ether 08:00:27:f4:ab:df txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) RX packets 29809 bytes 15340289 (14.6 MiB) RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 28836 bytes 4186164 (3.9 MiB) TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10 loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) RX packets 13485 bytes 3606497 (3.4 MiB) RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 13485 bytes 3606497 (3.4 MiB) TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

I run the command: `ssh -fND 8080 username@host` on this guest virtual machine. I need to route all guest VM traffic through `127.0.0.1:8080` using `iptables`. How can I do it?

*I tried using the rule*:

`iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.2.15 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8080`, but that didn't work. As far as I understand, this rule does not work for local addresses.

Comment: Please explain your setup in greater detail!

Comment: @U. Wind As I understand what I wrote above, it apparently cannot be done using `iptables`, so I installed badvpn-tun2socks.